# Cache invalidation between two web applications

Tags: asp.net

I need to invalidate cache in a web application when related data is updated in another application (running on the same machine). Both applications use the same database. I know there's SqlCacheDependency. 
How do is it in terms of performance?
Is interprocess communication (e.g. using name pipes) an option in web applications? Does it outperform SqlCacheDependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple to do by just using web services or a page action in each webapp.  The web service can just clear a cached element whenever it is called.

When webapp A updates the data that is cached in webapp B, just have webapp A call the web service in webapp B that clears the cache and vice versa.  You can add authentication as well if you want to secure it etc.

Anytime I have had to communicate with another web application and perform an action within the context of the other app I have done it by exposing web services or pages (ashx files) that will perform whatever action I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a distributed cache instead, e.g. Velocity http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx